# Exception occurred while processing message. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden

Tags: oauth-2.0, blazor

I am following this [tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/securing-blazor-webassembly-apps/#Securing-the-API-with-Auth0) which secures my Blazor WebAssembly Apps with Auth2.com and I am using command line to run the program. I could completed all the steps successfully and I could the Blazor app. But for the last step, I got this error from the command line

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[3]
      Exception occurred while processing message. System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.  ---> System.ArgumentException: IDX20108: The address specified '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' is not valid as per HTTPS scheme. Please specify an https address for security reasons. If you want to test with http address, set the RequireHttps property  on IDocumentRetriever to false. (Parameter 'address')
```

and in my browser console, I get error below:
[image]

This is QuizViewer.razor which consume the API

```
@page "/quizViewer"
@attribute [Authorize]
@using QuizManagerClientHosted.Shared
@using System.Net.Http.Json

@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@using System.Net.Http.Headers

@inject HttpClient Http
@inject IAccessTokenProvider TokenProvider 

<h1>Take your quiz!</h1>
<p>Your current score is @currentScore</p>

@if (quiz == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    int quizIndex = 0;
    @foreach (var quizItem in quiz)
    {
        <section>
            <h3>@quizItem.Question</h3>
            <div class="form-check">
                @{
                    int choiceIndex = 0;
                    quizScores.Add(0);
                }
                @foreach (var choice in quizItem.Choices)
                {
                    int currentQuizIndex = quizIndex;
                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="@quizIndex" value="@choiceIndex" @onchange="@((eventArgs) => UpdateScore(Convert.ToInt32(eventArgs.Value), currentQuizIndex))" />@choice<br>

                    choiceIndex++;
                }
            </div>
        </section>

        quizIndex++;
    }
}


@code {
    List<QuizItem> quiz;
    List<int> quizScores = new List<int>();
    int currentScore = 0;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {

        using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "quiz"))
        {
            var tokenResult = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();

            if (tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token))
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                  new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Value);
                var response = await Http.SendAsync(requestMessage);
                quiz = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<QuizItem>>();
            }
        }

    }

    void UpdateScore(int chosenAnswerIndex, int quizIndex)
    {
        var quizItem = quiz[quizIndex];

        if (chosenAnswerIndex == quizItem.AnswerIndex)
        {
            quizScores[quizIndex] = quizItem.Score;
        }
        else
        {
            quizScores[quizIndex] = 0;
        }
        currentScore = quizScores.Sum();
    }
}
```

and this is the API controller

```
using QuizManagerClientHosted.Shared;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace QuizManagerClientHosted.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class QuizController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly List<QuizItem> Quiz = new List<QuizItem> {
            new QuizItem
                {
                    Question = "Which of the following is the name of a Leonardo da Vinci's masterpiece?",
                    Choices = new List<string> {"Sunflowers", "Mona Lisa", "The Kiss"},
                    AnswerIndex = 1,
                    Score = 3
                },
                new QuizItem
                {
                    Question = "Which of the following novels was written by Miguel de Cervantes?",
                    Choices = new List<string> {"The Ingenious Gentleman Don Quixote of La Mancia", "The Life of Gargantua and of Pantagruel", "One Hundred Years of Solitude"},
                    AnswerIndex = 0,
                    Score = 5
                }
            };

        [HttpGet]
        public List<QuizItem> Get()
        {
            return Quiz;
        }
    }
}
```

and Server startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;

namespace QuizManagerClientHosted.Server
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddAuthentication(options =>
      {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
      }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
      {
        options.Authority = Configuration["Auth0:Authority"];
        options.Audience = Configuration["Auth0:ApiIdentifier"];
      });

      services.AddControllersWithViews();
      services.AddRazorPages();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
      }
      else
      {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    
        app.UseHsts();
      }

      app.UseHttpsRedirection();
      app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
      app.UseStaticFiles();

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseAuthentication();
      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
      });
    }
  }
}
```

How do I fix this? Which part I configure wrongly?

Comment: Are you able from your browser to access the Auth0 discovery document?

Comment: How do I access the discovery document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each account in Auth0 has a discovery endpoint and you can find it by going to Settings for your Auth0 application and then under Advanced settings you will find the Endpoints tab.

Under there you will find your OpenID Configuration URL.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can access to that OpenId URL from browser. What else to check?

Comment: The error message complains about HTTPS is missing, have you added this discovery endpoint to your API (the /quiz endpoint)? can you verify that the API that receives the token actually gets the discovery document? Use a tool like Fiddler and investigate... feel free to add those requests to your question. How is the API protected? feel free to add your startup class here as well.

Comment: `have you added this discovery endpoint to your API (the /quiz endpoint)? can you verify that the API that receives the token actually gets the discovery document?` What this means? For the source code, I have added in the original post.

Comment: Thanks. I realized what I did wrong is I didn't put the correct `a unique identifier` when I register the API and this affects the last step which is to put the same value at `Default Audience`

Comment: Awesome! Glad you found the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you're following the Blazor WASM tutorial and you run into this error what most likely happened is you added `https://` to the Domain in `Server/appsettings.json`

`{ "Auth0": { "Domain": "https://something.auth0.com" } }`

The example code for the `Server/Program.cs` uses string interpolation to add the `https://`

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, c =>
    {
        // HERE
        c.Authority = $"https://{builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}";
        c.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Auth0:Audience"],
            // AND HERE
            ValidIssuer = $"https://{builder.Configuration["Auth0:Domain"]}"
        };
    });
```

So either remove `https://` from the `Server/appsettings.json` or remove it from `Server/Program.cs`